# REST - Should the resource structure match between all verbs?

Tags: rest

A friend of mine is developing a RESTful HTTP API. He showed his solution to an architect of the company who said that his solution was wrong because the resource exposed in a GET didn't have the same structure as the resource in the POST. That is, the resource returned on a GET had less fields than the one passed on a POST. The architect gave no arguments besides saying that this is not RESTful.

Is there any rule in REST architecture saying that the resource structure should be the same for any verb? If yes, why is this recommended?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Architectural contrains for REST are described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints

None of them describes something that the a response types (GET, POST, ...) should have same structure, however a `GET` result should have enough information to be able to do a `POST` or `DELETE` request (Manipulation of resources through representations). That's because you won't be able to modify or delete you resource if the required parameters for modify or delete are not able; for example from your `GET` you retrieve values `x` and `y` but also need value `z` to be able to do a `POST`, how would you be able to modify this resource?

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What happens, for example, if my resource is a 'user'. When I do a POST to create a new user, I pass a 'password' field. So I must return the password when I do a GET, since this information is necessary for a POST?

Comment: To create a `new` user there is no need to do a GET request prior to POST, because an interaction from the user is needed. When you read the constrains they that this is only required for `modify` and `delete`, so there is already a resource which exists and I think it is not preferable to send password each time you want to update your `user` resource.